# How to rotate a bone to a specific position programmatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Suppose I have a human skeleton standing upright in the following position:

[image: Human Skeleton in default position]

Say I want to modify the 3d model, so that it is raising one hand (everything else the same):

[image: Girl raising hand]

I couldn't find a picture of a skeleton standing upright, so I posted the above picture, but you can imagine if the skeleton was standing exactly how it was in the first picture, with the only difference being it had rotated its right should to raise its right hand perfectly upright, what would it look like?
To further illustrate the idea, if you visit this link:

[Motion capture visualisation with Blender](https://github.com/bqlabs/MotioSuit/blob/master/Blender/MotioSuit.py)

The code he uses to update the 3d model in blender is actually quite small and simple:

```
import bge
import math
from math import *
import mathutils
import time

import sys
#sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
import serial
import glob

port=''.join(glob.glob("/dev/ttyACM*"))
#port=''.join(glob.glob("/dev/ttyUSB*"))
#port=''.join(glob.glob("/dev/rfcomm"))  
ser = serial.Serial(port,115200)
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#Connect the suit first and after a ~second launch the script


# Get the whole bge scene
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
# Helper vars for convenience
source = scene.objects
# Get the whole Armature
main_arm = source.get('Armature')
ob = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner


def updateAngles():
    ser.write("a".encode('UTF-8'))
    s=ser.readline()[:-3].decode('UTF-8') #delete ";\r\n"
    angles=[x.split(',') for x in s.split(';')]
    for i in range(len(angles)):
        angles[i] = [float(x) for x in angles[i]]


    trunk = mathutils.Quaternion((angles[4][0],angles[4][1],angles[4][2],angles[4][3]))
    correction = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    trunk_out = correction*trunk

    upperLegR = mathutils.Quaternion((angles[5][0],angles[5][1],angles[5][2],angles[5][3]))
    correction = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    upperLegR_out = correction*upperLegR

    lowerLegR = mathutils.Quaternion((angles[6][0],angles[6][1],angles[6][2],angles[6][3]))
    correction = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    #correction = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    lowerLegR_out = correction*lowerLegR

    upperLegL = mathutils.Quaternion((angles[7][0],angles[7][1],angles[7][2],angles[7][3]))
    correction = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    upperLegL_out = correction*upperLegL

    lowerLegL = mathutils.Quaternion((angles[8][0],angles[8][1],angles[8][2],angles[8][3]))
    correction = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    lowerLegL_out = correction*lowerLegL

    ob.channels['armR'].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Vector([angles[0][0],angles[0][1],angles[0][2],angles[0][3]])
    ob.channels['forearmR'].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Vector([angles[1][0],angles[1][1],angles[1][2],angles[1][3]])
    ob.channels['armL'].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Vector([angles[2][0],angles[2][1],angles[2][2],angles[2][3]])
    ob.channels['forearmL'].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Vector([angles[3][0],angles[3][1],angles[3][2],angles[3][3]])
    ob.channels['trunk'].rotation_quaternion = trunk_out
    ob.channels['upperLegR'].rotation_quaternion = upperLegR_out
    ob.channels['lowerLegR'].rotation_quaternion = lowerLegR_out
    ob.channels['upperLegL'].rotation_quaternion = upperLegL_out
    ob.channels['lowerLegL'].rotation_quaternion = lowerLegL_out

    ob.update()
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Is there an equivalent way in Unity3d, to access a particular bone in a 3d model, and set its rotation ?

See this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=26&v=JddtxynTgLk

As you can see, he is reading the values from the sensor, and updating the 3d model in blender in real time. I've done the sensor part, but am just getting started with Unity, and was wondering how to access individual bones and set them similar to the above code.

EDIT: In Godot engine, they seem to be able to do it very simply, see the link below:

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/3d/working_with_3d_skeletons.html

```
extends Spatial
var skel
var id

func _ready():
    skel = get_node("skel")
    id = skel.find_bone("upperarm")
    print("bone id:", id)
    var parent = skel.get_bone_parent(id)
    print("bone parent id:", id)
    var t = skel.get_bone_pose(id)
    print("bone transform: ", t)
    set_process(true)

func _process(delta):
    var t = skel.get_bone_pose(id)
    t = t.rotated(Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 0.1 * delta)
    skel.set_bone_pose(id, t)
```

As you can see, in the Godot example also, once they get the bones id, they simply need to set the angle.

Comment: Bones in unity are just transforms, so you can use `transform.Find("...").localRotation = ...` to rotate them.

Comment: @shingo What will happen to bones that are attached to them ?

Comment: There are no bones in unity, just transforms. you could check a model in the hierachy window, usually there is a GameObject named `Bip01` (if you make biped animation in blender) under the model root.

Comment: @shingo What is the human skeleton in unity for then? Also, do you have a sample project that does what I need?